# xcode does not recognized the docsets I installed

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I installed iOS 8.1 docsets manually, aka downloaded here:
`devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/docsets/20141020/031-07735-A.dmg`

Then I found a `com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS8.1.iOSLibrary.docset` installed at `/`.

When I opened xcode the download tab still shows iOS 8.1 document is not installed. But the docsets works with Dash.app, so it's not broken.

So I guess this folder was mis-placed, anyone know where I should place it?

I'm running xcode 6 with mac 10.10

P.S I already tried the following location, each time I try I will quit xcode first ([These locations are from this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/downloads/docset-index.dvtdownloadableindex))

`/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets`
`~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets`

None of them works ;-(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is updated iOS 8.1 doc sets out. I believe that fixes the issue.

- https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/docsets/20141020/031-07892-A.dmg